# How to get the end-user seen text of an <option>

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have this code, with books of the bible all within a  element:

```
<option value="1">Genesis</option>
<option value="2">Exodus</option>
<option value="3">Leviticus</option>
<option value="4">Numbers</option>
<option value="5">Deuteronomy</option>
<option value="6">Joshua</option>
<option value="7">Judges</option>
```

To further explain, I have the value as the book ID, so when I go to fetch all the verses from my Database I can just refer to them by the book number.

But doing that, I have no way of getting the user viewed friendly name like "Genesis", so that I can format it like that.

How do I fetch this (the one currently selected, i.e. "Genesis" not '1') from JavaScript?

Comment: What do you mean by "getting the user viewed friendly name"? Where do you need to get it? Are you setting the `selected` attribute of one of the options, and you need to fetch the text of the selected one?

Comment: Edit made. Hopefully that will be more specific.

Comment: You're not really explaining where you're stuck. Do you not know how to fetch a `select` element? Or do you not know how to get the currently selected `option`? Or do you not know how to get the text content from the option?

Comment: Right now I only know how to get the current value (document.getElementById('selector').value) but I don't know how to get the text content of the selected option.

Comment: Save the result of `getElementById` to a variable like `sel`, and then do `sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text`. *(I'm assuming that you're fetching the `select` element)*

Comment: @cookiemonster It worked. If you want, you can form this comment into an answer so you can get awarded the points.

Comment: Sure, I'll put my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the result of your `getElementById` to a variable like `sel`, and then do this:

```
var text = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
```

Select elements have an `.options` property that gives you an array-like collection of all of its nested option elements. They also have a `.selectedIndex` property, which returns the index of the currently selected element.

Using the two of these, you can get the currently selected option. Then simply use `.text` to get the text content of the selected `option`.

---

If you don't need to support IE6/7, you can use `document.querySelector()` to make things a little shorter.

```
var text = document.querySelector("#the_select_id option:selected").text;
```

The `querySelector()` method returns a single element, or `null` if none was found. There's also a `querySelectorAll()` method that will return a collection of elements, useful for when your selector should match multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

If your parent element has name="books" as an attribute, and is a select element, then you can do this using jQuery:

```
var bookName = $('select[name="books"] option:selected').text();
```

If your parent element has an id="books" as an attribute, and is a select element, then you can do this using plain JavaScript (can probably be improved upon):

```
var books = document.getElementById('books');
var bookName = books.options[books.selectedIndex].text;
```